# Replace one column of array with another array in C#

Tags: c#

I have the array b with size (100 rows,1143600 columns). First, I read one column from this array (for example column 1234) and do some calculation on it and save the results on another array. 
Now, I want to replace this array(new array, its size is (100 row,1 column (ie: one column)) with the original one(column 1234 from array b).

```
float[][] b = Enumerable.Range(0, 1143600).Select(j => new float[100]).ToArray(); // Array b

float [] item_factor= b[zz];  //its new column after ding some calculation
```

How to replace the item_factor[] with the target column in array b?

Comment: This sounds like it involves array resizing, which is almost never a good idea. Am I understanding the question wrong?

Comment: No. i don't want to resize the array b. I just want to replace one column with another one (remove the previous value from that column and write new values instead of that) @LordTakkera

Comment: I'm confused here. It looks like array `b` is a jagged array with 1143600 "*rows*" and 100 "*columns*".

Comment: You're right @lc. It is typing error. Do you have any idea?

Comment: In your case, can't you just set `float[] item_factor = b[1234]` since it's a jagged array (array of arrays)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1143600; i++)
   b[1234][i] = new_column[i];
```

Or if I misunderstood, and you are trying to go the other way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1143600; i++)
   new_column[i] = b[1234][i];
```

Note, if the constants from your question are swapped, 1143600 just becomes 100 (and obviously trying to access row 1234 won't work, so you would have to pick a lower index).

Both are almost exactly identical. I declare an iteration variable "i" and instruct the program to execute the statement within the (implied) braces for each value of "i" from 0 to 1143600, incrementing by one each time. By assigning the target row the value of the source rows column (indexed by using i) I effectively "copy" the column over.

Here is the MSDN reference for a for loop: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx)

Let me know if I can clarify further!

Comment: thanks for response @LordTakkera. May you explain both. I can not clearly understand what did you do?

Comment: At line:  b[1234][i] = new_column[i];  i shows the column? if it shows the column, what is [1234]?. thanks in advance

Comment: I is the current index being copied at that line. [1234] is the source/target row of the multi-dimensional array.

Comment: @user3371238 both functions are performing the requested copy, so I'm not sure what you mean by "shows the column". "i" and "1234" are just indexes. The 1234 is the row being copied to or from, and i is the iteration variable, so it is every value from 0 to 1143600 by the time the loop exits. Please let me know if I can clarify this further.